# Django url parameters confusion

Tags: django, django-urls

Hi: I have the hope you can helpme with my "django existential doubt".

Every time Im ask google for this the same thing happens to me (english is not my mother tongue), I have this doubt, this confusion:

Whats is the name of this things???

"my/happy/int:year/"   this is called "url parameter"

but

"my/happy/year?y=2020"  also is called "url paramenter" or not??

Thank you for your ilumination!

Comment: Two things, `URL parameters` (or `path parameter`) and [`URL Query Parameter`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a URL parameter followed by an URL QUERY PARAMETER in other words, whenever there is a specific information searched or retrieved from the query the URL parameter will slightly change in order to find that exact info from that URL parameter with the selected query settings.